# Mouse Hover Action not working in selenium when we connect to the browser using existing session

Tags: selenium, action, mousehover

We have test cases to launch browser with extensions first using selenium and then execute other test scripts(not selenium) and again we call selenium scripts which will connect to already opened browser using session id and remote address url. Now  in our AUT we have to do Mouse Hover on few elements Here when we use the Perform() funtions provided in Actions class..Test script fails and gives the error as "org.openqa.selenium.json.jsonexception unable to determine type from:u Last 1 Characters read:U"

We get the same error when we do the perform action on any element.

Can anyone please help us on this issue?

It works perfectly when we launch new browser and launch AUT directly.I mean it works when we don't use the concept of connecting to existing browser using session Id and URL.

Comment: are you doing connections properly,
session Id and URL,

driver = new FirefoxDriver(); Then capabilities,
Then Url,
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("YOUR_URL"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());